# Failed to create 5th http connection in iOS4

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios4

In OS3.1.3, I can create 6 UIWebView in a single view to watch 6 MJPEG stream simultaneously.

For the same application, it can run in iOS4 without any code modification. 
But it can only show 4 liveview feed at the same time. And I cannot send any request afterward.
Is this a limitation for iOS4 for multitasking? 
Or I use some deprecated functions, and I need to replace them?

Any suggestion is helpful, and thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Jamie Chen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem. The connection counts is limited by Safari.
This URL can test the number of parallel connection counts.
http://www.spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/
And the connection count of Safari is 4 in iPhone4.
Now, I am looking for solution to increase the connection count.
But I am wondering if I can find out...

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to question memory usage.  I am guessing you are trying this on a 3G S, and if true, this means you have 256 MB memory.  The same is true for the iPad.  The iPhone 4 has 512 MB.

Have you checked to see how much memory each UIWebView/Video Stream is chewing up?

Comment: Even though the 3GS has 256MB of memory, *much* less than that will be available to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the same host? This could be a server or firewall issue where it only allows 4 concurrent connections from one client to one host.

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the same host.
In OS3.1.3, I can create 6 connections to the host.
But in iOS4, I can only create 4 connections to the same host.
Therefore, my first thought is the connection counts are limited by iOS4 due to multi-tasking. 
But I can't find relative document about it.

Maybe the header of requests sent from different OS are different.
And it is block from server side. I'll check it, thanks.