# How many simultaneous connections per domain does Safari on iOS allow?

Tags: ios, safari, httprequest, long-polling

I'm just wondering how many simultaneous connections per domain does <strike>iOS</strike> Safari on iOS allow?

I've got a web page that uses long polling (up to about 40 seconds) and I am under the impression that all HTTP requests get queued until the server responds to the polling request (testing on iOS6 on iPad 2). 
Is that a real possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm I found this other question on Stackoverflow: [Failed to create 5th http connection in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544478/failed-to-create-5th-http-connection-in-ios4)

There is a test page to run in the answer to that question: http://www.spasche.net/files/parallel_connections/.

The first time I run the test on an empty cache on my iPad 2 on Safari (iOS 6.1.3), I got a surprising:

*"Your browser seems to use 0 simultaneous connections to this server."*

On the second time and thereafter I got the following:

*"Your browser seems to use 5 simultaneous connections to this server."*

Comment: I got the exact same results you did on an iPhone 5s with 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Without your own queue code it is possible to handle only 5 simultaneous connections at one time. You can of course use NSOperationQueue for example, to handle more.

Please check out this resources for more info:

http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/01/on-ios-url-connection-parallelism-and.html

[Maximize the number of simultaneous http-downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089331/maximize-the-number-of-simultaneous-http-downloads)

Comment: Hey Artur! I amended the question, which in fact targets Safari on iOS, not iOS in general (I should have been more precise). Does the same limit apply?

Comment: Ah, ok. But I guess in Mobile Safari there will be the same limit cause this is the same API used in Safari. But I'm not sure.